# In what order should you include Jasmine scripts?

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

No where in the documentation does it tell you which scripts to include in which order. I would like to print to the console because I am running jasmine inside PhantomJS. What files should I use for this?

I'm trying:

```
bootstrap.js
console.js
jasmine.js

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.ConsoleReporter(console.log));
```

but it gives

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new jasmine.ConsoleReporter(console.log)')
```

Answer (score 0):

`jasmine.js` needs to come before `console.js`, as `console.js` adds `ConsoleReporter()` as a method to the `jasmine` object.

Comment: for me it only works if I do: jasmine.js, then jasmine-html.js, then boot.js, then console.js. I'm not sure if console.js is even doing anything though.

Comment: User1873073, You might see it in action when running with a headless browser from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the included sample btml runner. I found that any add on must load after boot.js. For example,  Jasmine-jquery and teamcity reporters. These usually attach themselves to the global Jasmine object which is configured in boot.